# Grouping items DataTable

Tags: c#, json, datatable, webapi

Here is the Datatable I am having.

[image]

To get a nested JSON like this:

```json
[
   {
      "ID":"1",
      "Subject":"Eng",
      "Marks":70,
      "CHILD":[
         {
            "ID":"1",
            "Subject":"Math",
            "Marks":90
         },
         {
            "ID":"1",
            "Subject":"Phy",
            "Marks":80
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "ID":"2",
      "Subject":"Eng",
      "Marks":75,
      "CHILD":[
         {
            "ID":"1",
            "Subject":"Math",
            "Marks":85
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "ID":"3",
      "Subject":"Math",
      "Marks":60,
      "CHILD":[
         
      ]
   }
]
```

If an ID has N number of `mark details` , 1st `mark detail` will become header and remaining (N-1) will be displayed under CHILD array tag.
Please help me to create a nested JSON (group by ID) like the example above. Please advise.

Comment: How will you decide that english is your master element?

Comment: I think you can handle it with Newtonsoft and LINQ.

Comment: @AmitGupta Subject is stroed in asc order. So Enlish is coming as master element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class something like this -

```
> class myClass  {
>     public string Id {get;set;}
>     public string Subject {get;set;}
>     public int Marks {get;set;}
>     public List<myClass> CHILD {get;set;}  }
```

Then loop through the datatable and fill the data on object of this class.
Then use NewtonSoft to convert the class to JSON.

Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: I have milions of record such as , so I think looping is not a good option. I am trying to handle it using LINQ , but not getting the expected output

Comment: @ArijitMondal millions records should be filtered on the database side before Json conversion occurs. I suppose that it would be hard to handle json for millions of record. Modern [MS SQL has the 'for json' feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) you may find it useful

Comment: BTW Linq only provide us a way to minimize the code and help us to provide the better readable and flexible code. Internally it is looping the records. If you are worried about the performance then you can create your JSON in database itself. Almost all modern RDMS provide way to create and read the JSON.